# How to set /dev/irobot_create as the Turtlebot base device

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since I have multiple USB devices attached I'd like to make sure that when I run minimal.launch it uses /dev/irobot_create rather than the default /dev/ttyUSB0.  What's the best way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39809/how-to-set-/dev/irobot_create-as-the-turtlebot-base-device/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to supply the port parameter in minimal.launch. See http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_node#Parameters

You'll have to change minimal.launch as follows:

FROM:

```
<!-- Turtlebot Driver -->
<node pkg="turtlebot_node" type="turtlebot_node.py" name="turtlebot_node" output="screen" respawn="true" args="--respawnable">
  <param name="bonus" value="false" />
  <param name="update_rate" value="30.0" />
</node>
```

TO:

```
<!-- Turtlebot Driver -->
<node pkg="turtlebot_node" type="turtlebot_node.py" name="turtlebot_node" output="screen" respawn="true" args="--respawnable">
  <param name="bonus" value="false" />
  <param name="update_rate" value="30.0" />
  <param name="port" value="/dev/irobot_create" />
</node>
```

The ROS wiki contains more documentation [here](http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML) if you want to read up on supplying parameters through launch files.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1